# Ruby on Rails terminal issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Rails 5, but all the commands i can execute are `rails new project_name`and `rails -v`
other commands like `rails server`, `rails db:schema:dump`
give following output

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /home/alexa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]  # Skip Action Mailer files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                    # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]    # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                    # Skip test files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

I am on ubuntu 16.04, database is mysql. What kind of problem can it be?
I used this guide to install Rails https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a rails project with the command: `rails new my_app_name`.
2. **Change directory into the folder: `cd my_app_name`**.
3. Run whatever other commands you like, e.g. `rails server`.

Comment: You can also run `rails new .` to create a rails project *in the current folder* - but this is typically not what you want to do!